# Producing broken image in template, using python 2.7, django 1.10 and pillow 3.0.0

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, python-imaging-library

I basically want to produce 3 kinds of thumbnails in different sizes at the time of uploading the Image. and then reference them in the templates

models.py

```
def thumbnail_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.productimage.product.slug, filename)

THUMB_CHOICES = (
    ("hd", "HD"),
    ("sd", "SD"),
    ("micro", "Micro"),
)

class Thumbnail(models.Model):
    productimage = models.ForeignKey(ProductImages)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=THUMB_CHOICES, default='hd')
    height = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True) 
    media = models.ImageField(
        width_field = "width",
        height_field = "height",
        blank=True, 
        null=True, 
        upload_to=thumbnail_location)

    def __unicode__(self): # __str__(self):
        return str(self.media.path)


import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
import random

from django.core.files import File


def create_new_thumb(media_path, instance, owner_slug, max_length, max_width):
        filename = os.path.basename(media_path)
        thumb = Image.open(media_path)
        size = (max_length, max_width)
        thumb.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        temp_loc = "%s/%s/tmp" %(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, owner_slug)
        if not os.path.exists(temp_loc):
            os.makedirs(temp_loc)
        temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_loc, filename)
        if os.path.exists(temp_file_path):
            temp_path = os.path.join(temp_loc, "%s" %(random.random()))
            os.makedirs(temp_path)
            temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, filename)

        temp_image = open(temp_file_path, "w")
        thumb.save(temp_image)
        thumb_data = open(temp_file_path, "r")

        thumb_file = File(thumb_data)
        instance.media.save(filename, thumb_file)
        shutil.rmtree(temp_loc, ignore_errors=True)
        return True

def product_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.media:
        hd, hd_created = Thumbnail.objects.get_or_create(productimage=instance, type='hd')
        sd, sd_created = Thumbnail.objects.get_or_create(productimage=instance, type='sd')
        micro, micro_created = Thumbnail.objects.get_or_create(productimage=instance, type='micro')

        hd_max = (500, 500)
        sd_max = (350, 350)
        micro_max = (150, 150)

        media_path = instance.media.path
        owner_slug = instance.product.slug
        if hd_created:

        if sd_created:
            create_new_thumb(media_path, sd, owner_slug, sd_max[0], sd_max[1])

        if micro_created:
            create_new_thumb(media_path, micro, owner_slug, micro_max[0], micro_max[1])

post_save.connect(product_post_save_receiver, sender=ProductImages)
```

produces such:

[This is the image produced in the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1JPN.png)

template.html

```
{% for img in image_set %}

<img src="{{img.media.url}} "/>

{% else %}
<p>No image</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The (tmp folder) has not been removed right from the admin side and its not showing the formed thumbnails' sizes. I have added a screenshot of the same after forming the thumbnails in the admin but lacking the sizes

Answer (score 1):

just change a bit on the open(temp_file_path, "wb") and (temp_file_path, "rb") instead of (temp_file_path, "w") and (temp_file_path, "r"). I had the same issue but was fixed its the change in the OS

```
open(temp_file_path, "wb") and (temp_file_path, "rb")
```